# td colspan not stable

Tags: html, css

I have a table here, with a td and its given colspan. I have a column in the table with a link which when clicked, makes a panel 'expand' below the current row.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-default">
        <tr>
            <th>Column A</th>
            <th>Column B</th>
            <th>Column C</th>
            <th>Column D</th>
            <th>Column E</th>
            <th>Column F</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="http://www.example.com">ABCD</a>
            </td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>400</td>
            <td>testing</td>
            <td>
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1" href="#" class="collapsed" aria-expanded="false">Show</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td id="1" class="collapse" colspan="6" style="height: 0px;">Lorem ipsum</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click `Show`, the cell with id `1` first expands correctly to span the entire table row, but then immediately shrinks back to the width of the first cell. Does anyone know how I can keep the width of the cell constant and spanning the entire row? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about adding the corresponding css and js?

Comment: This code does not work without the corresponding CSS rules. Perhaps you should simply toggle the `style.display` property of the whole row and leave the column height by default ?

Comment: please add your CSS and JQ here. otherwise we can't help you

Comment: I have only used this code so far.

Comment: i can't see the behaviour you are talking about when clicking the `show` button

Comment: Regardless of what is happening when clicking `show`. It would be better to not show\hide table cells itself but an element within the cell. `<tr><td colspan="6"><span id="1" class="collapse">Lorem ipsum</span></td></tr>`.

Comment: @VDWWD Actually, that fixed it! Thank you!!